# Set view permission depending on request matchdict in Pyramid

Tags: python, pyramid

If I add an route and then a view , how could I set the view permission depending on request matchdict in Pyramid? I mean something like:

```
config.add_route('full_reg', '{base}/reg/{id}/full', factory=RegContextFactory)
config.add_view(view=RegCustomView, attr='full_reg', route_name='full_reg', request_method='GET', 
    permission=request.matchdict["base"])
```

Of course , I don't have the "request" object there, but how could I do so ?

**Edit:** adding code.
Here are the classes:

```
class RegContextFactory():  

    @property
    def __acl__(self):
        return [
            (Allow, 'g:users', 'x'),
            (Allow, 'g:users2', 'y'),
        ]   

    def __init__(self, request):
        self.request = request

class RegCustomView():    

    def __init__(self, context, request):
        self.context = context
        self.request = request

    def full_reg(self):
         # if the user is not from users group, or the base param is not 'x',
         #then this view should be forbidden
         base = self.request.matchdict.get('base')
         return Response('ok')
```

Comment: Please show your `RegCustomView` class. You are mis-using the `view` argument of `config.add_view`. Also, the `attr` argument is not usually needed.
Check out the following resources:
1) http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/tutorials/wiki2/authorization.html
2) http://michael.merickel.org/projects/pyramid_auth_demo/index.html
3) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10266652/how-do-i-restrict-permissions-based-on-the-single-page-id-in-the-url/10268939
4) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16169590/pyramid-multiple-resource-factories-how-to

Comment: I edited the question, putting the class codes (edited for purposes). In my case, the `attr`     argument is needed, and the `view` argument is not mis-used since the code works fine. But the real problem here is: If i am a user from 'users' group , i should have the 'x' permission, but this 'x' should come from matchdict.

Comment: Sorry, misread your view argument as `RegContextFactory` instead of `RegCustomView`

Comment: This section of documentation shows how to use the matchdict for returning the appropriate ```Effective Principal```:
http://michael.merickel.org/projects/pyramid_auth_demo/group_security.html#simple-object-level-authorization

Comment: How'd it work for you user1538560?

Comment: My needs are very specific, i need a kind of "base level security" for each user. That means, the user has pemissions on that base he created.

Comment: Does this Gist help? https://gist.github.com/ianjosephwilson/8870333

Comment: It would helped me a lot about 3 days ago. I have found a workaround solution using the request from the user callback function. Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution using user callback function:

```
# This should be in RegContextFacory
__acl__ = [
    (Allow, 'group:viewers', 'view'),
    (Allow, 'group:creators', 'create'),
    (Allow, 'group:editors', 'edit'),
    (Allow, 'group:deleters', 'delete'),
    (Allow, Authenticated, ALL_PERMISSIONS),
    (Deny, Everyone, ALL_PERMISSIONS),
]


def user_callback(user_name, request):

    if user_name == 'admin':
        return 'Authenticated'

    base = request.matchdict.get('base')
    resource = request.matchdict.get('id')
    auth_provider = AuthProvider(user_name, base, resource)
    return auth_provider.get_permission() #Should return somtehing like ['group:viewers']
```